# Issues with GET request on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, get

I'm trying to create a simple GET request on Android Studio using an AsyncTask, as shown in the code snippet below. When debugging, I notice that when I do url.openConnection(), the HttpURLConnection has a responseCode of -1. I've looked all over to see what is the issue, and I still can't figure it out. When I tried a GET request on Visual Studio, I was able to get the response correctly.

Here is the main code for my AsyncTask:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any): String {
            var result: String
            var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
            try {
                val url = URL(myMockURLstring)
                connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection // *** messes up here ***
                connection.doOutput = true
                connection.doInput = true
                connection.instanceFollowRedirects = false
                connection.requestMethod = "GET"
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
                connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8")
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
                connection.useCaches = false
                val httpResult: Int = connection.responseCode // Gets the status code from an HTTP response message.

                if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    //inputstreamreader code
                    
                } else {
                    result = connection.responseMessage
                }

            } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
                result = "Connection Timeout"
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                result = "Error : " + e.message
            } finally {
                connection?.disconnect()
            }

            return result
        }
```

I also have the following two lines in my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any idea what I should add or change to get it to work on Android Studio?

EDIT: Changed to GET

Comment: you are saying issue with `GET` request but you have requestMethod of `POST` type

Comment: if you want to use `GET` request you should change this `requestMethod="POST"` TO `requestMethod="GET"`

Comment: Not only that. `connection.doOutput = true` well that should be false.

Comment: And your issue is not with Android Studio but with HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to declare connection as this?

```
val url = URL(myMockURLstring)
val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
```

Then you can test the return of this URL before start to do anything else:

```
if (connection.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    try {
        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect()
    }
} else {
    println("ERROR ${connection.responseCode}")
}
```

Try setting your `connection.doOutput = false` too, like @blackapps said.

Also, it might be a better option to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html), a more modern way to deal with async tasks.